# How to plot optional args in python

Tags: python, plot

I need a clue for a way to plot an optional argument depending on the user choice:

To clarify:
I have an excel sheet with a lot of columns and I want a way for the user to plot two columns against each other.
One of my columns is fixed, but the other I need to be chosen by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1) [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)

2) Using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)